# How to create Illuminate\Routing\Route object by route name with parameters?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create Illuminate\Routing\Route object by route name with parameters, I stuck here :

```
$parameters = ['firstParam', 'secondParam'];
$route = \Route::getRoutes()->getByName($routeName);
```

I can create Illuminate\Routing\Route object but then how to bind parameters ? 
When I call :

```
$route->parameters();
```

I get this error "Route is not bound. ", so does anybody how to bind parameters ?

PS. I can see function :

```
setParameter(string $name, mixed $value)
```

but I don't want to use param name, I just want create route object by route name and params...

I want something like :

```
Route::create($routeName, ['paramFirst', 'paramSecond']);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of needing the route object?

Comment: @Sandeesh I want create function which will check if logged user can access given route, something like canAccessRoute($routeName, $params){...}

Comment: Should the url look like this?
 http://www.example.com/routename/paramFirst/paramSecond  http://www.example.com/routename/1/2

Comment: For that purpose you could (should?) use Gates: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#gates

Comment: @TobiasBeuving why are you asking that ?

Comment: @TobiasBeuving I use Gates now but this canAccessRoute($routeName, $params){...} would be much better for me...

Answer (score 2):

You may get `Illuminate\Routing\Route` object by route name  without parameters. But you may set parameters to `$parameters` public property.

```
//Illuminate\Routing\Route object

$route = Route::getRoutes()->getByName('route_name'); 

//Set parameters
$route->parameters = ['id' => 2];
```